# battery not showing on laptop

Tags: battery

Hello i have a problem where i cant find my laptop battery anywhere in the system. I looked for a lot of fixes but at the end i have a problem where `acpi` and `upower` doesn't give any output. My laptop works fine with internal battery but i can't see its power status.

`acpi -b` no output

`upower -i` no output

settings->power->Power not showing battery

`sudo vi /etc/default/grub` #output:

```
#tried changing default to acpi=force
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

```
uname -a
5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu
```

```
upower -e
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

```
Laptop: Fujitsu lifebook A3510
```

thanks for help and if I can give you more or better info please let me know.

Comment: What is the `upower -e` command output?

Comment: Which model is your laptop?

Comment: Fujitsu lifebook A3510